# Is it possible for open api 3.0 to use the ui from swagger 2.0?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger, openapi

I'm currently working on `spring boot 2.0` and i just found out that `swagger 2.0` didnt support webflux. So the solution is to use `open api 3.0` instead of `swagger 2.0`. My question is, is there any possible way to use the ui from `swagger 2.0` for `open api 3.0`? Thanks

Comment: It is possible to document webflux project with swagger 2.0. See this project: https://github.com/pgilad/spring-boot-webflux-swagger-starter

Comment: @KrzysztofMajewski thanks for the comment,yeah i knew that but unfortunately it still uses snapshot dependency so i cant really use it until it is in release version. Is there any other way to use open api 3.0 but use old swagger 2.0 ui template